# Is there a way to do module.exports a variable within a http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Okay so I have scoured the internet to find the answer to this but all have failed. So my problem is saving and storing information from a https GET requests and using it elsewhere. Yes I know this is dealing with asynchronous nature Node JS. My idea is to use module.exports.json_data and require that in a new file in the same folder and access that file.

```
const https = require("https");
var json;
function getting_order(){

    var options = {
        hostname: "some_url.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/certain/endpoint/",
        method: "GET"
    };


    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let responseBody = "";

        res.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        res.on('data',(chunk) => {
            responseBody += chunk;
        })

        res.on('end',() =>{
            json = JSON.parse(responseBody)
            exports.json = json;
        })

    });
    req.end();
};

module.exports.getting_order = getting_order;
```

Notice the exports.json = json in:

```
res.on('end',() =>{
   json = JSON.parse(responseBody)
   exports.json = json;
})
```

So my question is, does this even work and actually save that json to be used elsewhere in another file?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But when you import the module, you never know whether the `.json` is ready or how to wait for it when it's not. So **don't do this**. Export a promise instead (or even better, return it from your function).

Comment: Don't do this.  If you need to persist to the file system, use `fs.writeFile()`.  Don't make your code harder to understand or violate expected patterns.

Comment: @zero298 That still has a race condition; I don't see how that helps if they just need to operate on dynamic data.

Comment: @DaveNewton There are multiple issues with this code.  I only addressed the fact that the OP is trying to overload the exports for something that it shouldn't really be used for.  Bergi already pointed out the async issue.  The entire approach is flawed.

Comment: @zero298 *shrug* I just don't see how involving the file system is relevant. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible, however by looking into your code, according to me, you're trying to send `json` back to whoever is calling `getting_order` function. So you should pass *callback function* as argument and call that function on receiving `json`.

```
const https = require("https");
var json;
function getting_order(callback){

    var options = {
        hostname: "some_url.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/certain/endpoint/",
        method: "GET"
    };


    var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        let responseBody = "";

        res.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        res.on('data',(chunk) => {
            responseBody += chunk;
        })

        res.on('end',() =>{
            json = JSON.parse(responseBody)
            callback(json);
        })

    });
    req.end();
};

module.exports.getting_order =
```

**HOW TO USE ABOVE SOLUTION**

```
//call like this
getting_order(function(order_json) {
    //you will receive json here
    console.log(order_json);
});
```